# Unable to clear WooComerce cart when navigating to a new page inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

Im trying to empty the Woocomerce cart whenever a visitor navigates to a specific page (with id #1).

**Environment:**

WP 5.4.2

Woocomerce 4.2.2

Woodmart theme

Litespeed cache (disabled) [and applied these recommendations](https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2017/05/31/wpw-fixing-lscachewoocommerce-conflicts/)

Tested with google chrome/Firefox browsers. both incognito and normal mode.

none of the answers [on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954448/how-to-clear-a-woocommerce-cart) helped

Im using this code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_clear_cart' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart() {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
    if( $post->ID == 1) {
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->session->set('cart', array());
    }
}
```

Result:

1. customer goes to product page and adds products to cart.(my template shows the product in the mini-cart)
2. customer navigates to page id 1.
3. products still appears in mini-cart/or when navigating to cart page.
4. cart is **only emptied after using CTRL+F5 to reload browser** without cache. or after a few times navigating between pages.

Insights:

- **Expected result happens correctly** when im logged in as admin (cart emptied when navigating to page 1)
- when **emptying customer sessions** (WooCommerce/Status/Tools -> Clear customer sessions ) after user adds product (between step 1 and 2 ) navigating to page id 1 **gives expected result.**
- im suspecting its a browser cache issue.
- when printing out `WC()->session` when page#1 loads i can see the cart items from step 1.

Is there some WC method to clear the specific customer session from the DB programatically ?

i also tried this code, but none of these gave me expected result

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_clear_cart' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart() {
    if( $post->ID == 1) {
        WC()->session->set( 'cart', null );
        WC()->session->set( 'cart_totals', null );

        $cart = WC()->cart; 
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

                $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key ); // remove it from cart
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_front_page() && isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
        WC()->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }
}
```

This for the front page, replace with your page of choice.

Comment: as you can see, im using this code. its not working for me